# clipping rasters using python in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, clipping, python-standalone

I am still a novice in python, besides that am trying to come up with stand alone program  to carry out several geoprocessing processes i.e. clipping , creating hillshade and slope. Am using Tkinter to create the GUI for the stand alone. I have managed to come up with the following script , whoever am encountering an error that DLL module load failed. Any idea how I can fix the error ???

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import os, sys, time 
import operator
from osgeo import gdal, gdalnumeric, ogr, osr
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
#import ogr
import subprocess

master = Tk()

inraster = 'F:/practice/data/DEM/srtm_44_13_mau_prj36s.tif'
inshape = 'F:/practice/data/Boundary/eastern_mau.shp'

ds = ogr.Open(inshape)
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)

lyr.ResetReading()
ft = lyr.GetNextFeature()

while ft:
    country_name = ft.GetFieldAsString('admin')

    outraster = inraster.replace('.tif','_%s.tif'% country_name.replace(' ','_' ))
    subprocess.call(['gdalwarp', inraster, outraster,'-cutline',inshape,'-crop_to_cutline','-cwhere',"'admin'='%s'" % country_name])

    ft = lyr.GetNextFeature()

ds = None
```

This is Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\GIS programming\project scripts\sem proj\gamesGUI.py", line 264, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal, gdalnumeric, ogr, osr
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo_init_.py", line 21, in <module>
    gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init_.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
         _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: please provide the error information.

Comment: File "F:\GIS programming\project scripts\sem proj\gamesGUI.py", line 264, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal, gdalnumeric, ogr, osr
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Am trying to carry out geoprocessing techiques in a standalone..and everytime i try to run any of the geoprocessing scripts i find the same error about osgeo

Comment: please don't post errors in the comments, they are impossible to read. You can edit the question.

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: I notice the traceback goes from `F:\ ` to `C:\ ` have you tried running your program from the same drive that `osgeo` is installed?

Comment: from Tkinter import *

import arcpy
import os
import os.path
import Tkinter,Tkconstants
import tkFileDialog,Tkconstants